# searching in partition view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have a partiton view `scheduletest` which is union of the tables `scheduletest20120522`, `scheduletest20120523`, `scheduletest20120524`, `scheduletest20120525` like this from -7 to +7 days.

The columms are `date`, `starttime` and check constraint is on `starttime`.

While I am searching the `scheduletest` with statement

```
select top 10 * from scheduletest where starttime>'2012-05-24 12:00:00'
```

it is searching in the tables from `scheduletest20120524`, `scheduletest20120525`, `scheduletest20120526`.

While using the statement

```
select top 10 * from  scheduletest where starttime>getdate()
```

It is searching in all tables from -7 to +7 days like  `scheduletest20120522`, `scheduletest20120523` etc.

I tried with `sp_executesql` it is taking more time than this.

Please provide suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Top` clause but you are not sorting the selected data. Thus your request is non-deterministic and can give you different results on each execution.

Try to add a `order by` in your select.

Comment: even though i added order by , it is searching in all tables. my question is it is searching all tables if we give the getdate(). While we give date as '2012-05-24' it is searching in only tables from '2012-05-24'

Comment: @santhosh do you have the same result with a `select top 10 * from scheduletest where starttime>cast('2012-05-24 12:00:00' as datetime)`?

Comment: yes i have same results, there is no change in results.I want the way to search only in corresponding tables. Not all tables.while ia m using select top 10 * from scheduletest where starttime>'2012-05-24 12:00:00' it is searching in correct tables but while giving the statemnet select top 10 * from scheduletest where starttime>getdate() it is searching unncessarily all tables